# Certificate pinning ignoring hostname validation

Tags: android, validation, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've just implemented certificate pinning following a tutorial I found. But now I've noticed that it's ignoring hostname validation and god knows what more it's ignoring.

here is what i have:

SSLSocketFactory:

```
public class PinningSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    PubKeyManager pkm;

    public PinningSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
        KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        pkm  = new PubKeyManager();

        TrustManager tm[] = { pkm };

        sslContext.init(null, tm, null);

    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        pkm.setContext(context);
    }
}
```

X509TrustManager:

```
public class PubKeyManager implements X509TrustManager {

    public Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

        if (chain == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("checkServerTrusted: X509Certificate array is null");
        }

        if (!(chain.length > 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("checkServerTrusted: X509Certificate is empty");
        }

        if (!(null != authType && authType.equalsIgnoreCase("RSA"))) {
            throw new CertificateException("checkServerTrusted: AuthType is not RSA");
        }

        // Perform customary SSL/TLS checks
        // get request cert
        try {
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
            tmf.init((KeyStore) null);

            for (TrustManager trustManager : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
                ((X509TrustManager) trustManager).checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CertificateException(e);
        }

        //get stored certificate

        expected = //compare both certs

        if (!expected) {
            throw new CertificateException("checkServerTrusted");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

Getting HttpClient:

```
public DefaultHttpClient getPinningHttpClient(){

    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        PinningSSLSocketFactory sf = new PinningSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setContext(context);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new DefaultHttpClient();
}
```

My question is how do I resolve the missing hostname validation and any other missing validations that may be broken doing things this way.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of certificate/pubkey pinning is that you know that a specific host has a specific certificate or public key. Validation of hostname and certificate chain are only needed if you don't know what the certificate should be. Pinning is the stronger proof that you talk to the expected peer. But of course you should associate hostname and pinning information in your application, i.e. don't use pinning information from one site to verify some other site.

Apart from that don't use just "... a tutorial I found". At OWASP you can find [good information](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) about the topic and also example code.

Comment: I've basically followed the example project on that page to do what I have now. The problem is that we placed the cert on the Quality server and it accepted the request even with the url not matching the one on the certificate. Só i'm assuming that using my `PinningSSLSocketFactory` has somehow ignored the Hostname validation. If I use the default `SSLSocketFactory` It doesn't allow the connection because of the Hostname validation.

Comment: @HugoAlves: again - Pinning is the stronger method of validation because you know the certificate  or public key.  Validating chain and hostname is only necessary if you need to check if the previously unknown certificate you got can be trusted. This means it is ok to omit the hostname check.

Comment: Ok thks for the help. Sense this is an area I have little expertise in I was afraid that it was a possible way to attack by redirecting the user's requests to the attacker's machine and stealing their information or that I had opened some other way of attack. I was thinking hostname validation would protect this.

Comment: I've tested putting a copy of certificate on a random machine and accessing it. Only the public key was validated, the url of the machine was not the same as the certificate. If I remove the certificate pinning code Android simply rejects the connection with this exception: `java.io.IOException: Hostname 'myurl.com' was not verified`. Doesn't this leave a huge open door to an easy redirect to the attacker's server?

Comment: @HugoAlves: to cite myself: "But of course you should associate hostname and pinning information in your application, i.e. don't use pinning information from one site to verify some other site."

Comment: I'm sry i think you missunderstood me then. My problem is that using the above code, android ignores validating hostnames and I wanted it to start validating again. Even if i add `sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);` it still lets url that don't match the hostname on the certificate. If i change my code removing my `PinningSSLSocketFactory` it starts rejecting the connection as expected.

Comment: If I understand you right your problem is that after a compromise of the server and the loss of the private key the attacker can use the same certificate at other servers and you will not notice. This is true but the problem is not that the attacker can do this but that the private key is compromised and thus no longer private. Thus the basic assumption about TLS security is broken. In this case it does not matter if the attacker hacks you from the owned server, from another server or uses the private key for a man-in-the-middle attack on the same server name.

Comment: Hmm ok, my bad then. Tks for taking the time to explain things to me :)